# Increase video buffer for HLS (Apple HTTP Live Stream), possible?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, wowza, http-streaming

We're using Wowza 3.5 in our server to stream videos, and JW Player for the player.

The streaming of videos are working fine when viewed in iPhone and iPad.

What we are trying to do now is, when a video is playing on an iOS device and a user paused it we would like the video to buffer (download) while it is paused so even if the user lost connection to the internet he could still watch the video until. Currently it is only buffering for 30 seconds to 1 minute.

How could we increase this buffer time to possibly buffer / download the whole video while the player is paused?

Is this even possible in HLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible when you're playing a video using HLS in a webpage using the default browser.

You need to create your own app to control the video buffer when playing videos using HLS.

Comment: How can I made my own control for buffer?

Answer (score 0):

There is an App with Wowza called nDVR, you can pause, play and record using nDVR. Also I think you can increase the buffer length in application.xml, make sure.